# How to put new Zend_Db_Expr in where?

Tags: zend-framework

I dont know how should i put new Zend_Db_Expr in where condition. My code is

```
$select = $this->objDB->select()
    ->from(array('tra' => 'transactions'), array('id', 'amount'))
    ->where( new Zend_Db_Expr('CAST(amount AS FLOAT)') < 3);
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: try `->where(new Zend_Db_Expr('CAST(amount AS FLOAT)< 3'));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Zend_Db_Expr for your case.

It should be just:

```
->where('CAST(amount AS FLOAT) < 3');
```